# Is it possible to keep approvals in a stacked Merge Request when the prior Merge Request is merged?

Tags: gitlab

Suppose I have a chain (or stack) of Merge Requests (MRs) as follows...

- `MR1` – Branch `B` to Branch `A`.
- `MR2` – Branch `C` to Branch `B`.

... and both MRs have been reviewed and approved.

When I merge `MR1`, Branch `B` is deleted and GitLab is smart enough to change the destination branch of `MR2` from Branch `B` to Branch `A`. This is great. This is what I expect to happen.

Sadly, GitLab also removes the approvals from `MR2` which means I have to go back and request another review of `MR2`. (My project's approval rules require MRs to have at least one approval.)

Is there a Setting in GitLab which will keep the approvals on an MR when the destination branch is automatically changed as described in the scenario above?

Comment: There is an [approval setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html#approval-settings) that [removes approvals when the source (or target) branch changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html#remove-all-approvals-when-commits-are-added-to-the-source-branch). Since your target branch changes in this scenario, that might be the setting impacting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no Setting in GitLab which will keep the approvals in a stacked Merge Request (let's call it `MR2`) when the prior Merge Request (let's call it `MR1`) is merged and GitLab automatically changes the destination branch of `MR2` to the destination branch of `MR1`. (GitLab changes the destination branch of `MR2` because the original destination branch of `MR2` is deleted as part of the merge of `MR1`.)

I have created a feature request for this in the GitLab project [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/372602). Please upvote it if you would find this feature useful

Special thank you to [systech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747944/sytech) for his/her help with this in his/her answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73573240/1071320)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [approval setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html#approval-settings) that [removes approvals when the source (or target) branch changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html#remove-all-approvals-when-commits-are-added-to-the-source-branch). Since your target branch changes in this scenario, that is likely the setting causing the behavior you describe.

There is no special case or consideration for how/why the target branch changes when this setting applies. For example, there is no distinction between changing the target branch manually or when it is changed automatically as the result of the branch being merged/deleted -- in both cases, this setting will remove existing approvals.

To avoid this approval issue, you might:

1. Disable that approval setting OR
2. Set the target of both merge requests to branch A so that there is no change in the target branch for MR2 when MR1 is merged and branch B is deleted

Comment: Thank you for your response  What I'm taking from your answer and the links that you shared is that there is no Setting in GitLab which will keep the approvals in a Merge Request when the destination branch is automatically changed as described in the scenario in my question. So, by extension, stacked Merge Requests are better avoided in GitLab when the project requires the "Remove all approvals when commits are added to the source branch" setting to be turned on. The key bit in the documentation for me is this: "... approvals are reset if the target branch is changed."

Comment: I will reach out to GitLab with a support request to ask whether there are any plans to better support stacked Merge Requests. I'll update this thread when I get a response.

Comment: I created an issue in the [GitLab project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab). See [Issue #372602](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/372602). Let's see what comes of it. I'll update this thread as that issue develops.